# Non-EU citizen living in the UK, moving to Italy with Italian husband

Tags: visa, eu, italy, italy-aire

I hope someone can help with a step-by-step explanation as I haven't got a clear understanding as a result of my communication with Turkish and Italian consulates.

I am a Turkish national. I've been living in the UK for 10 years (no British passport) and married for 1.5 years to an Italian citizen (practicing his EU treaty, 7 years). We have decided to move to Milano, Italy, in two months and intend to stay there permanently. In the meantime, I hold a residence card of family member of an EU citizen, issued by the UK. This enables me to live and work in the UK and travel in the EU without a visa (under the EU law and not UK law). So, I don't have any problem entering Italy without a visa for short visits.

- First, we still haven't got our marriage registered in AIRE, the Italian consulate in London yet. We're wondering whether it makes sense to register it here in London or when we arrive in Italy, considering we have only 2 months left here. I don't want to be told that I should have done it in London when I am already in Italy. Also, I am scared that it might take months if we do it through AIRE.
- Do I need to apply for a visa or a residence card (similar to what I have here in the UK) to remain in Italy with my husband? Do I need to apply for it at the Italian consulate in London or in Italy? Where in Italy if so?
- Are there any other documents/certifications I should obtain while in Italy?

Comment: I don't know the answer (hopefully someone with first-hand experience will be able to answer) but you might also look into getting a residence card as the spouse of an EU citizen (vs. Italian citizen) using [the Surinder Singh route](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surinder_Singh_route).

Comment: You'll need to get a residence permit.  To do that, you'll need to prove to the office issuing the permit that you are married.  You should therefore find out *from that office* what its requirements are as far as registering the marriage.

Comment: I’d strongly advise you to apply for U.K. settled status as long as you can. That way, if you leave the U.K. and change your mind within five years, you can return without problems. Same for your husband. I know what you intend but five years is a long time and things can change.